# Get Twitter handle for an NFT contract address

Tags: web-scraping, twitter, moralis

I'm looking to get the official Twitter handle from an OS Verified project, programmatically.

I've tried calling the "collections" OS API, but the twitter_username field seems to rarely be populated with anything but "null" even for verified projects.

I've tried scraping the data manually with fetch but I got 1020 errors likely due to cloudflare protections.

Has anyone else used Moralis NFT or some other GraphHQ like service to obtain the Twitter handle of a given NFT project (starting out with a contract address)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Ubiquity](https://blockdaemon.com/documentation/ubiquity-api/nft-api/get-nft-collection-by-id/) API. They have an endpoint for collection metadata which also includes the Twitter account name

```
https://ubiquity.api.blockdaemon.com/v1/nft/ethereum/mainnet/collection?contract_address=0xBC4CA0EdA7647A8aB7C2061c2E118A18a936f13D
```

This will give you the following response

```
{
"collection": {
    "id": "4203aedd-7964-5fe1-b932-eb8c4fda7822",
    "name": "Bored Ape Yacht Club",
    "description": "The Bored Ape Yacht Club is a collection of 10,000 unique Bored Ape NFTs— unique digital collectibles living on the Ethereum blockchain. Your Bored Ape doubles as your Yacht Club membership card, and grants access to members-only benefits, the first of which is access to THE BATHROOM, a collaborative graffiti board. Future areas and perks can be unlocked by the community through roadmap activation. Visit www.BoredApeYachtClub.com for more details.",
    "logo": "https://ubiquity.api.blockdaemon.com/v1/nft/media/ethereum/mainnet/collection/4203aedd-7964-5fe1-b932-eb8c4fda7822/logo.png",
    "banner": "https://ubiquity.api.blockdaemon.com/v1/nft/media/ethereum/mainnet/collection/4203aedd-7964-5fe1-b932-eb8c4fda7822/banner.jpeg",
    "verified": true,
    "contracts": [
        {
            "address": "0xBC4CA0EdA7647A8aB7C2061c2E118A18a936f13D",
            "name": "BoredApeYachtClub",
            "symbol": "BAYC",
            "description": "",
            "image_url": "https://ubiquity.api.blockdaemon.com/v1/nft/media/ethereum/mainnet/",
            "type": "ERC721"
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "discord_url": "https://discord.gg/3P5K3dzgdB",
        "external_url": "http://www.boredapeyachtclub.com/",
        "twitter_username": "BoredApeYC"
    },
    "sub_collection": []
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  OS also fixed their API, but stopped giving API keys - so this might help out some others.